# How do I re-enable the regular title bar in Firefox Quantum?

Tags: windows, title-bar, firefox-quantum

Is there a way to re-enable the regular title bar for the program window in Firefox (V57, Quantum) for Windows (currently Windows 7)?

By default the windowbuttons (close window, minimize window, restore window) are integrated into the tab bar and the title bar is hidden. There is no setting under "view" in the menu bar nor under settings?! At least I can not find anything there. Thanks!

[image: Titlebar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By now I found the answer myself (FF V57). You have to right click on the tool bar (where the symbols are) and click customize. At the very bottom you will find a check box called "Title Bar". Check it and the title bar will reaper again.

[image]